# Value match from column range X to return value from same row, but different column range

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have set up two tabs on the on Google Sheets document. In Tab1 I have ColumnA (days of the week) and ColumnB (employees). I have created Named Ranges for both of these. In Tab2, I want to find all the employees from ColumnB that match the value 'Monday' within Tab1 ColumnA and return the value of ColumnB of the same row. Ideally, I would like all matching values to be listed in the one cell.

I have gotten as far as

```
=IF('Tab1'!A:A="Monday","value(Tab1'!B:B)","")
```

Which is returning the false/blank value correctly.

When the value 'Monday' from Tab1 actually does match, it returns #VALUE! and not the actual value from ColumnB. I think this is because I'm not specifying that it's a text value, not a number, but I'm not certain how to do so. Lastly, the values returns, including the blank ones, are on individual rows corresponding to where they are on Tab1 which again, I'm not sure how to correct.

Find the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzFCz15-B0XAVkc2j4aQPx6yjTGmzguTqdxLKsQ65Y8/edit?usp=sharing

If anyone can guide me to the solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: Find the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TzFCz15-B0XAVkc2j4aQPx6yjTGmzguTqdxLKsQ65Y8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **A2** cell and drag to the right:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER('Task Status'!$E3:$E, 'Task Status'!$H3:$H=A$1))
```

[image: 0]